# Chart.js scale which increases by x (arbitary number) for each tick

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a data set where the differences between data can be extremely large. I am wondering if there is any way to have a scale which increases it's size by say 10 times for each tick. So the start may be one/zero, the next 10, the next 100, then 1000 and so on. Is this at all possible? Nothing suggests so far that it is?

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic scale is supported:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        type: 'logarithmic',
```